# UK visa refusal due to misinterpretation

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, serial-refusals

I had two UK standard visit visa refusals in this month of June (I am a researcher with one year renewable contract visiting a university in London as part of an assignment from my university). The first refusal was due to some miss interpretations of the invitation letter by the Entry clearance officer (the letter was generic and issued to all the visiting researchers of that university). The second refusal was due to a big misinterpretation of my banking statement (I had some reversal entries (refunds on my debit card) and some small cash deposits in the previous 6 months) The officer didn't check the transaction and cash withdrawals prior to these incoming funds in question (the reversal entries and the small cash deposits) and judged that these funds are most-likely not reflecting my financial situation.

The other reason is that I requested a Business visit visa, and I had no business travel history in my passport (fresh passport).

If I can get a Schengen visa, would that help me with my future UK visa applications ?

Another question: In my second UK visa application, the officer sad that I requested 45 days, but I only requested 4 days, Is there any channel or a way to get clarifications ?

How long is the recommended cooling off period in this type of situation. I need to go to the UK in the next year for two weeks to take part of a scientific training in this university ?.

The second refusal letter

[image: The second refusal letter]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you email them pointing out their mistakes? It's not like they're doing you any favors by processing your application--you have paid a fee--and you have a right to fair evaluation.

Comment: I already canceled my trip, although I want to clarify things so these refusals won't affect my future applications

Comment: You should still email them. If they change the decision, you should get your visa sticker even if you are not going. It will help you for future applications.

Comment: My application went the the Sheffield office. Do I need to email this office, or my local British embassy ?

Comment: It's not clear that your bank statements were misinterpreted at all. You're supposed to explain them, but you apparently didn't. To me, it sounds very unusual to have such a large amount of money refunded to your debit cards in such a short time.

Comment: When you go to an ATM,  you withdraw 700£, and then there is a reversal entry to you account is that illegal (both transaction are on the statement) ?. When you buy from ebay (paypal), and your item do not arrive and you get refunded, is that illegal (both transactions on the statement) ?

Comment: I just checked it, when you find -500 +500 from the same source  would that be an other source of income hahahahahahhahaaa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are currently in a serial refusals situation.  The first answer for this type of situation is "stop applying"!  While this advice seems merely pedantic, serial refusals indicate a fundamental misunderstanding of how the process works and what they want to see.

---

> If I can get a Schengen visa, would that help me with my future UK
>   visa applications ?

Yes. All evidence of peripatetic activities in the affluent countries of Europe and North America is massively helpful. "Helpful" means it adds credibility to the applicant's premise; it is not, however, a *guarantee* of success.

> Another question: In my second UK visa application, the officer sad
>   that I requested 45 days, but I only requested 4 days, Is there any
>   channel or a way to get clarifications ?

Generally no. They will never reverse a decision once it has been made. They might, however, be willing to issue you an edited version of your refusal notice that corrects the typo.

> How long is the recommended cooling off period in this type of
>   situation.

There is no cooling-off period for a UK refusal, you can make a fresh application on the same day they return your passport.  Moreover, there is no "recommended" amount of elapsed time and anyone saying differently is just internet babble spewing out recklessly uninformed pap.

What's important is to stop thinking in terms of cooling off periods and instead think in terms of personal circumstances and how these can be changed. It means if you wait 6 months or a year and still have the same job, the same lifestyle, the same cash flows, same homeland connections, and the same everything else, you will get refused again.  To improve your chances of success, you should seek a root-level change in your social, economic, and lifestyle conditions; these are the things they will be looking for.

Professional advice from a member of the [UK Law Society with a practice area in visitor visas](http://www.ilpa.org.uk/search-directory.php) may be able to help you present your personal circumstances in a more favourable light, but those people earn fees for their work and so it depends upon your own appetite for mobility.

> I want to clarify things so these refusals won't affect my future
>   applications

Clarifications and explanations go into a fresh application; it's the only way they will acknowledge something.  That's why it's important to get professional help so that your pattern of serial refusals is fixed.

---

from comments

> Thank you for you answer. Can i send a review request and say that I
>   want only to get clarifications and not appeal ?

Once again the answer is 'no', and firmly so.  You can always send them something or even make a formal complaint to [Marsham Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Marsham_Street), but all you will get is a form letter from the correspondence unit advising you to make a fresh application.

---

Note: after this answer was posted, you modified your question to include scans of your refusal notice. Once again thanks for observing site courtesy.  Your refusal is on grounds V 4.2 a+c.  This is a very common, garden-variety refusal and there's nothing special about yours either positive or negative.  Our recommended next step for you is to carefully read [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) and consider instructing a UK solicitor.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Can i send a review request and say that I only want to get clarifications and not appeal ?

Comment: Do I have to contact the Sheffield office or my local British embassy ?

Comment: @Lilo answer amended; you really need to get off the clarification thing. It has no value where UKVI is concerned

Comment: My employer (the university) cannot accept the refusal letter of 45 days. as they were paying only for 5 days.

Comment: @Lilo in that case you should print out this answer and show it to your employer

Comment: @Lilo thanks for the 'accepted answer' by the way; it's wonderfully encouraging when people demonstrate courtesy to this site's model.