# UK visa application refused for misrepresentation that I over stayed in UK in 2015, but I have never been in the UK

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, deception

My UK visa application was refused and I 10 years of deception. there is no right to appeal or administrative review.

Basis of misrepresentation that I overstayed in the UK in 2015, but in actuality I never made misrepresentation and I have never been to the UK in my entire lifetime

Seems like my name is matching with some other person from his database,  Please tell me what I can do?

Comment: Were you refused on 320(7a) or 320(7b)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UK visa refusal due to misinterpretation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/95865/uk-visa-refusal-due-to-misinterpretation)

Comment: @L.Dutch This is way more serious than v4.2 (a,b,c) and the answer is different

Comment: I imagine such a refusal would need a match on biometrics, not just the name. Posting the full refusal reason might help shed some light.

Comment: I have edited the title and text of your question for clarity, and I have tried to not change the meaning of your original wording. If you disagree with my changes, you can press the "edit" button below your question, and "roll back" my changes to return the question to your original text.

Answer (score 10):

It will depend on what grounds you were refused

---

320(7a) is the most favorable possibility for you, since you aren't actually banned *yet* and can reapply even though an extreme level of scrutiny will be applied to **any further application**

> You should note that because this application for entry clearance has been
> refused under paragraph 320 (7A) of the Immigration Rules, any future
> applications may also be refused under paragraph 320 (7B) of the Immigration
> Rules
> [General grounds for refusal](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/307893/GGFR_Sec5v16.0_EXT.pdf)

You *can* reapply **BUT** :

For this, you are **extremely** encouraged to get the services of a **legit** (there are **many** *agents* that are far from legit) immigration law solicitor for advice as a single mistake on any application will likely trigger a 320(7b) refusal which entails the actual ban.

Immigration adviser is a regulated profession in the UK, and all non-legal professionals (sollicitors and barristers are regulated in other ways and aren't in the OISC registry) are to be registered under the [Office of the Immigration Services Commissioner](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/office-of-the-immigration-services-commissioner). You can check if a company is legally regulated by asking them their 10-digit OISC number and typing it on the OISC site.

---

If you are refused under 320(7b) now, you're very out of luck as you're already banned, and automatic refusal is warranted on your case for 10 years.

In this case, judicial review is the only way you can try through a solicitor (or just wait)

Comment: *get the services of a legit (there are many agents that are far from legit) immigration law solicitor* cannot emphasise this enough, outside the UK there are many 'visa agents' who as far as I can tell either do very little or actively encourage their clients to lie or create fake documents. Do not trust anyone to help you with your UK visa, particularly in such a delicate situation, who is not working for an accredited UK based company.

Comment: Related question [How do I find an Immigration lawyer/solicitor to help with my UK visa application](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89170/how-do-i-find-an-immigration-lawyer-solicitor-to-help-with-my-uk-visa-applicatio)

Comment: @MJeffryes how can one tell if a UK-based company is accredited?

Comment: @user253751 Immigration adviser is a regulated profession in the UK, and all non-legal professionals are to be registered under the [Office of the Immigration Services Commissioner](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/office-of-the-immigration-services-commissioner). You can check if a company is legally regulated by asking them their 10-digit OISC number and typing it on the OISC site

Comment: I find the comments and answer interesting that none mention anything about OP statement that they have never been in the UK but the charge is about being in the UK. Is it really impossible for this to happen, and so people (more or less rightly) assume that OP misunderstood something? Or that the (7b) is so powerful that even if it's wrongful, nothing can be done by OP themselves? Because I would assume that this would be a clear-cut mistake on their part (if everything in OP story is true), just show that they've never been to UK.

Comment: @justhalf The process is always (7a) (the warning) then (7b) (the fornal ban, which can only be reviewed in court). The reason that a adviser (or even better a solicitor) is really recommended here is that they can figure out if this is a name matchup or a biometrics matchup. If that is a biometrics, it would be basically impossible, 1st for the story to be true then 2nd to not get a (7b) on reapplication. If that's a name mixup (very unlikely), then there is a slim chance of rehabilitation

Comment: So overall the situation is judged very unlikely, right? Got it.

Comment: @justhalf More than unlikely in my opinion, if not lost. Matchups *can* happen but biometrics (fingerprints+photos) have been a part of a UKV, since at least 2005 and were surely compulsory by 2010+, so a name-only match is **very** unlikely and biometrics likely matched up for this conclusion to be drawn. It is not out of the equation that OP tried to cover its own overstay and failed